# How to configure the locale to be different from the default locale for a user on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: command-line, users, language-support, locale

On Ubuntu Server 12.04, how can I configure an account to use a locale other than the system default local? Say if I wanted Russian users to be able to use Russian in the terminal ... and Polish users to use Polish, how can I achieve that?

The default locale is supposed to remain at `en_US` in its various incarnations (it defaults to the UTF-8 variant).

The ideal solution would be something where I can set it in `adduser` and friends, but I didn't find such option.

Note: *no* X11 and the question is solely about the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in `~/.profile` of your user: `export LANG=prefered_local`